# select and delete a record without the information of primary key

Tags: java, .net, mysql, sql-server, database

My requirement is to select a record first (the record may not have a primary key) and the delete the same record.

Below is the flow :

1. Select all records from table.
2. while (resultset.next()), get the single record.
3. delete the record.

The code has to work with all databases.As this is going to be genric service.

This is a java database service.Currently it is implemented for Oracle.We are using ROWID to identify each record.But it fails for other databases as some databases don't have ROWID and similar concept.I want to make this service generic.I want to apply some logic other than ROWID

Any ideas ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: this code has to work with .net and java also ? didn't you forget php or c ?

Comment: My suggestion: research SQL a little further. You can do this in a single query, no need to select and then delete things individually.

Comment: why don't you just run a delete statement for the row in question?

Comment: THis is an impossible task. Without a primary key or other unique identifier, you cannot correctly delete records. Plus you need to start thinking in terms of sets, you would never do a task like this through looping through all the records in a table.

Comment: I don't think you'd ever iterate over something to delete it, rather create a more meaningfull deletion SQL statement, such as: "DELETE FROM Customers c WHERE c.age > 20". That way you would not need a primary key for identification.

Comment: Sounds like a mighty complicate and slow solution to delete all rows from a table.

Comment: The only way this would make sense is if something ought to be done with the record in the code prior to deletion.

Comment: You should definetly rethink about what you're asking. It is impossible to answer a question unclear as this. A generic service or a database query? What is it that you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

How about `DELETE FROM [TABLE]` with the name of that table? Or if you want to delete by some criteria like columns values, why not put that directly into your statement as well using a `WHERE` clause?

There's a language for database operations: SQL. Use that where appropriate.

Comment: Or just DROP the table and recreate it with PK or UKC :D

Answer (score 1):

And how do you plan to identify this one record, given there's no unique identifiers? At best you'll have to compare all the other records, but that's no guarantee of uniqueness, you could still end up deleting the "wrong" record, even though all the fields match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete from table
where somefield = 'somevalue'
```